# Issue about weakreferences

Tags: android, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have one or two `weakreferences` in my program.

Just for example:

```
ClassX myClassX= new ClassX(); //Line 1
WeakReference<ClassX> myWeakClassX = new WeakReference<ClassX>(myClassX); //Line 2
if(myWeakClassX.get() != null) // Line 3
{
    //do something with reference //Line 4
}
```

**My question:**

How is it ensured that when at line 3 `myWeakClassX.get()` has a valid reference to an `Object`, it is also valid at line 4? I can imagine that if you are really unlucky, the GC does his job exactly "between" line 3 and 4. Please bear with me, because i'm relatively new to Android/Java..

Thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, first thing to understand is Garbage Collector reclaims memory from objects which are eligible for garbage collection

**Question is how is the eligibility defined ?**

eligibility is decided based upon which kind of references are pointing to that object.

**Why we need Weak Reference ?**

If you create a Strong reference to an object, the object cannot be garbage collected. Whereas, A weak reference, simply put, is a reference that isn't strong enough to force an object to remain in memory. Weak references allow you to leverage the garbage collector's ability to determine reachability for you, so you don't have to do it yourself.

**Issue here**

Weak reference isn't strong enough to prevent garbage collection, so you may find (if there are no strong references to the class) that myWeakClassX.get() suddenly starts returning null.

**What is the other option ?**

***Soft Reference***

You use a SoftReference when you want the referenced object to stay alive until the host process is running low on memory. The object will not be eligible for collection until the collector needs to free memory. Loosely stated, binding a SoftReference means, "Pin the object until you can't anymore."

This way myWeakClassX.get() will not be null.

**Examples of where we can use ?**

1. In any secondary threads where you create a reference to the activity.

   WeakReference weakActivity;

   //In AsyncTask onPostExecute Method
   Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
   if (activity != null) {
   // do your stuff with activity here
   }
2. If you can referring to an Activity context elsewhere, you can use Weak reference.
3. While handling bitmap resources in imageview in another thread
   http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html
4. If you are creating any Hashmap or any widget to hold any data, you can use Weak reference. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/WeakHashMap.html
5. Usage is unlimited. It is up to the developer to utilize it at right places.

Comment: Sounds good but also here, if you are running out of Memory between line 3 and 4, Even the `softreference` will return null. So why using `weak-orsoftreferences` if you are not really able to ensure that they are return null and your program can crash with a NPE..?

Comment: @MMike, If your Android OS issues low memory warning, all activities with low priority even if the objects hold strong reference will be GCed. But we need different references to manage the GC eligibility behavior. So, it is good to use Weak/soft reference at right place.

Comment: Sounds plausible. Can you tell me some examples which are the right `places` to use them? Would appreciate that

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that during line 3 and 4 the `get()` operation can return `null`, as it is supposed to do. You can always copy the reference you get from `get()` operation into a variable (thus making it strong again) and use it within the `if` block safely. Because you still have a strong reference, the object will not be garbage collected.

A simple check for null can be:

```
if(myWeakClassX.get() != null)
{
  ClassX myref = myWeakClassX.get();
  if(myref != null) {
      //use it
  }
}
```

However in-case of activities, having a strong reference does not guarantee that the activity will not be destroyed and although you have a strong reference that is valid, the activity may throw exceptions when you try to use it as it is destroyed.
Example: If you are keep reference for an activity inside some AsyncTask, the activity might get destroyed (i.e orientation change) before AsyncTask runs. And although you will have a reference to it, you will get exceptions when you try to update UI.
That is where you can create a WeakRefernce to activity inside the AsyncTask and if the get() operation start returning null, you will know that the activity was destroyed by whatever reason and not try to use it.

Comment: If i put the reference which i get from `get()` method inside the `if-scope` into a `strong-reference`. No one can ensure, that it is not null at that point again. For me, it's just moving the problem to "another place". Maybe a `Softreference` is better in that case? In fact you can only be sure to have a valid reference if you use a `strongreference`. So why using `weak-or softreferences` if they can lead to NPEs..?

Comment: I have given one example of WeakRerence in case of Activities. If you are keep reference for an activity inside some AsyncTask, the activity might get destroyed (i.e orientation change) before AsyncTask runs. And although you will have a reference to it, you will get exceptions when you try to update UI. You can always check for null in case of weak reference - check updated answer

Comment: Now it's clear to me. You are right. And after the `if-Statement` has finished the strong reference is eligible for GC, correct?

Comment: yeah, the reference will be out of scope than. and GC can collect it whenever it wants.

Comment: Thank you, can only accept one answere, so you got a upvote from my side